# Quick fork link for a GitHub repository

Tags: github

Well i'm searching around for this, but I can't find the answer anywhere yet.

Is it possible to make a link (in markdown) that redirects to the fork popup?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is *exactly* what your looking for but in markdown you could do this:

`[Fork this on github](https://github.com/user_name_here/repo_name_here/fork)`

Comment: Is there a similar link for `star` as well? I tried `/star` but that didn't work.

Comment: Any procedure to give star to the repository through this way?